# Need a Javascript function that would work like this .includes(['1', '2', '3'])

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, filter

Apologies if this has been asked before and if what I am asking doesn't make sense please let me know and I will do my best to clarify.

What I am looking for is a function that works the same way as the .includes() function does, but I would like it to accept an array. It seems that the "includes" function only looks for 1 needle in a haystack instead of multiple needles.

Any help with this would be great.

For Context: I am working in Vuejs, and I have a computed property that is taking an array of objects and each object contains another array of colors. To sort I am adding color codes to the selectedColors array and would like to filter my searchArray results based on the selectedColors array.

Below is what I have in my computed property as of now... and obviously when the selectedColors array has anything in it, no results are returned.

```
colorArray: function() {
      return this.searchArray.filter(station => {
        if (this.selectedColors) {
          return station.colors.includes(this.selectedColors)
        } else {
          return this.searchArray
        }
      })
    }
```

Here is an example of my searchArray:

```
this.searchArray: [
    {title: 'first', colors: ['BL', 'YL']},
    {title: 'second', colors: ['YL']},
    {title: 'third', colors: ['OR', 'GR']},
]
```

Here is an example of my selectedColorsArray:

```
this.selectedColors: ['BL', 'YL']
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your `else` should just `return true` since you're within the `filter()` callback

Comment: Good call. I have updated my code to reflect that change. Thanks

Comment: What logic do you want to apply? `colors` contains **all** entries in `selectedColors` or **any** entry?

Comment: I would like it to be all inclusive. So the ```searchArray``` would return all results based on what is in the ```selectedColors``` array

Comment: That's not what I asked you. Say `selectedColors` contains `['a', 'b']` and you have `station1` with colors `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `station2` with colors `['a', 'c']`, do they both get returned or only `station1`?

Comment: Apologies. I misread, ```colors``` can contains ANY entry